# Making Python dictionary case insensitive by aggregating keys

Tags: python, dictionary, case-insensitive

I have a dictionary with a lot of keys that are different from each other because of the dictionary's case sensitivity. I'd like to have it all in one lower case key, but with all values of those keys aggregated.

I have something like:

```
>>> data
{'Blue Car': 73, 'blue Car': 21, 'yellow car': 10, 'Yellow Car': 15, 'Red Car': 12, 'Red car': 17, 'red car': 10, 'Yellow car': 18}
```

And the output should be like:

```
>>> newData
{'blue car': 94, 'yellow car': 43, 'red car': 39}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts? There are tons of similar questions on StackOverflow, did you try any of those approaches?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any question that was about this specific problem, the "case insensitive dictionary" ones were not solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionaries and set comprehensions:

```
>>> {x: sum(v for k, v in data.items() if k.lower()==x) for x in set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), data))}
{'red car': 39, 'blue car': 94, 'yellow car': 43}
```

or more user friendly:

```
SET = set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), data))
SUM = lambda x: sum(v for k, v in data.items() if k.lower()==x)
newData = {x: SUM(x) for x in SET}

# newData = {'red car': 39, 'blue car': 94, 'yellow car': 43}
```

### Explained:

```
SET = set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), data))
```

obtains all unique lowercase keys,

```
SUM = lambda x: sum(v for k, v in data.items() if k.lower()==x)
```

returns the sum of the values for keys in `data` matching the unique key, and

```
{x: SUM(x) for x in SET}
```

will match this value as a part of pair with the matching key, for every key in the set.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'm still learning comprehensions, so thanks for the explanation aswell.

Comment: This is definitely the least readable, least efficient method posted so far. I'll note you haven't actually used a set comprehension either. You could have done `{x.lower() for x in data}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

newData = defaultdict(int)

for k in data:
    newData[k.lower()]+=data.get(k,0)

# {'blue car': 94, 'red car': 39, 'yellow car': 43}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: why not use `data.get(k)`?

Comment: Well, it's unnecessary and will make your code a bit slower. Better yet, iterate over `d.items()`.

Comment: even if using `.get`, it would be more logical to do it with default value of 0 like `.get(k, 0)`. However, `.get` is absolutely not required here

Comment: Very constructive comments. Mods made.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, `defaultdict` is mainly to avoid setting the key. Otherwise you'd get a `KeyError` exception.

Comment: Are you sure? I am using `int.__radd__`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
newData = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    newData[k.lower()] += v
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def compress(data):
    newDict = dict()
    for key in data:
        newDict[key.lower()] = newDict.get(key.lower(), default=0) + data[key]
    return newDict
```

Answer (score 1):

I would subclass `dict` and override the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` magic methods

```
class NormalizedDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self,key.lower())
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        return dict.__setitem__(self,key.lower(),value)

myDict = NormalizedDict()
myDict['aPPles'] =5
print myDict
```

of coarse we can take this further and autosum for you

```
class NormalizedSumDict(NormalizedDict):
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        if key.lower() in self and type(self[key]) == type(value):
           try:
              value = value + self[key]
           except:
              pass
        NormalizedDict.__setitem__(self,key,value)
    def update(self,other):
        for k,v in other.items():
            self[k] = v

d = NormalizedSumDict()
d['aPPles']=5
d['Apples']=2
print d
```